# get previous Entry

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter widget that will remember the previous entry. The problem I am having is the that the button method I made erases the previous entry every time its pressed.

```
from Tkinter import *

class step1():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getTextbook(self):
        temp = str(textbook.get())
        textbook.delete(0, END) 
        x = " "
        x += temp
        print x 

    def equal_button(self):
        print getTextbook(self) 


root = Tk()
root.title("step1")
root.geometry("600x600")
s = step1()

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
label = Label(app, text = "step1")
label.grid()

textbook = Entry(app, justify=RIGHT)
textbook.grid(row=0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)

textbook2 = Entry(app, justify=RIGHT) 
textbook2.grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)

button1 = Button(app, text = "Return", command = lambda: s.getTextbook())
button1.grid() 

button2 = Button(app, text="Equal")
button2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: store it in a different variable maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `X` in your `getTextbook()` is being overwritten every time you set it to `" "`. Try a list instead, and append each entry to the list when the button is pressed:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

textbookList = []

def getTextbook():
    textbookList.append(textbook.get())
    textbook.delete(0,END)
    print textbookList

textbook = Entry(root)
textbook.pack()

btn1 = Button(root, text='Return', command=getTextbook)
btn1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time answer that. I thought about doing this, but I am trying to preserve the class. And I realize that I didn't communicate that properly. So I am wondering is there a way to call a global variable to a class?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If you rewrite a variable, it's rewritten. Why not have a list or dict handle all the values? You can still retrieve them as needed.

Comment: I am trying to design a calculator using tkinter. and to that I need  to understand how to use classes in tkinter. So that is why I want my class to remember the variable.